# How to convert "indent level" to SUBTOTAL formula with a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, automation

I've been given over 100 excel sheets, each with multiple thousands of entries that look like the following:

[image]

I need to edit these files, delete certain rows, and the total roll-up prices need to be correct. Unfortunately, column C is hardcoded with the values. **How do I convert the "Price" column to use the subtotal function as in the rightmost column?** I do not want to go through each file line by line.

I have the indent level, which should theoretically make this easy, but I've never really worked with macro's before. I'm not sure how this would be accomplished with just formulas, but I suppose it could be done.

I can either modify column C or create an additional column, D.

Comment: [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) Maybe? Could you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1485897/edit) to clarify the desired outcome and how you would get to it?

Comment: First SORT Indent Column & then go with Group & Subtotal.

Comment: @RajeshS Sorting wouldn't work because some level 1's are piece parts, some are roll-ups (same with level 2 and 3). I need to make sure the link between the roll-up and the levels below it are not lost.

Answer (score 0):

*This tricky method along with `SUMIF` solves the issue.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Sort data range `A45:B61` using `Indent` as key in ascending order.
- Enter this formula in Cell `D46` & fill down till needed.

  `=IF(A46<>A45,SUMIF(A$46:A$61,A46,B$46:B$61),"")`
- Another possible solution is `Group & Subtotal`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Sorting wouldn't work because some level 1's are piece parts, some are roll-ups (same with level 2 and 3). I need to make sure the link between the roll-up and the levels below it are not lost.

Comment: @dberm22,, Sorting works perfectly,, I've used INDENT as shown by you above with OP and my SUBTOTAL also works, I've suggested SORT for organized look otherwise SUMIF can read data even are Random!!